# Are alternate suggestions in “username already taken” errors useful?

Tags: registration, tooltips, username

I know it’s industry standard to provide alternate suggestions when a user tries to input a username that is already taken while registering.

It occurs to me that users A) ignore the suggestions or B) use one of the suggestions only to forget it later because they didn’t create it themselves. Providing the suggestions seems to be, at best, a waste of time and resources and, at worst, leading to more login errors in the future.

Comment: If you use emails for logins (as suggested by Mervin), then your question is just "is it a worthwhile use of resources to develop this feature". The answer to that will depend a lot on the size of your userbase, and how much trouble they have finding available usernames.

Answer (score 10):

### The idea here is about simplifying the process for users by making it easier to see what available options are there and allowing them to choose instead of going by a trial by error approach where users try multiple variations of user names and find all are taken leading to additional frustration.

**Taking an example of signing up for yahoo mail**

> I tried creating an account with mervinjohnsingh and the error I get
>   below is as follows
>
> [image]

While this informs that the username is not available, now I will need to plough through multiple user name combinations until I find what user name options are available to me as shown below

> [image]
>
> [image]

On the other hand, twitter even before I create an username gives me potential choices which I can choose which makes my decision making process easier if I find something which I like

[image]

The choice of providing additional options also **informs users of the different combinations they can use to create an user name** such as the addition of numbers or using using periods or dashes to create an unique user name.

---

The above examples are applicable to cases where an username forms the basis of your interactions such as your new email id or twitter id but if you are looking at other websites where the registration process is just get the user into the system, there are two alternatives

1. Allow the users to use just email ids to register for the system : This is because users will most likely already have an available email id which they will be able to remember. To quote this [smashing magazine article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/05/innovative-techniques-to-simplify-signups-and-logins/)

> **ALLOW USERS TO LOG IN WITH THEIR EMAIL ADDRESS** Remembering an email address is easier than remembering a user name. User names can
>   be unwieldy, and people remember their email address because they use
>   email all the time. Give users the option to log in with their email
>   address as well as a user name. The flexibility could save them the
>   time and headache of recovering the user name if they forget it.

2. **If an username is required but the priority is to ensure users can get into the system first, consider asking them for an username later**. To quote the same smashing magazine article

> Sign-up forms typically ask users to create a name that is unique to
>   the website. However, coming up with a unique user name that’s not
>   taken could take trial and error and, thus, time. Instead of hassling
>   people for a user name when they sign up, you might want to consider
>   asking afterwards. This way, you won’t lose sign-ups from frustrated
>   users, and you’ll prevent users from creating random and forgettable
>   names just to satisfy the form’s requirements.